# Is Other git feature removed from Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to create a new pipeline in my new Azure devops account and I am not able to see the feature "other Git" in the new Azure DevOps account. The same feature is available in one of my old Azure DevOps accounts. May I know could someone help me to understand why I am missing this feature in the new azure devops account?

**OLD Azure Devops account**

[image: OLD Azure Devops account]

**New Azure Devops account**

[image: New Azure Devops account]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see "**Other Git**" option you need to **turn off** the "**Disable creation of classic build pipelines**" option in organization settings.

[image]